# How do I navigate horizontally in less?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, less, cursor

I'm viewing a *wide* (not necessary long) file using the `less` utility, without line wrapping.

I can move right and left using my arrow keys (and even that's due to terminal magic I'm not well-versed in, since "right arrow" is not an character you can type in); but I don't know to:

- Move a single character to the left/right
- Move a full screen to the left/right
- Move a hal-screen to the left/right
- Move to the beginning of the line
- Move to the end of the line

Now, looking at the help page, I see:

```
     23   ESC-)  RightArrow *  Right one half screen width (or N positions).
     24   ESC-(  LeftArrow  *  Left  one half screen width (or N positions).
     25   ESC-}  ^RightArrow   Right to last column displayed.
     26   ESC-{  ^LeftArrow    Left  to first column.
```

But that doesn't seem to to work for me. Also, it's weird to press Esc+Shift+0 (to get `ESC+)`).

How does horizontal movement actually work? And - can I make it easier, e.g. for Ctrl+RightArrow and Ctrl+LeftArrow at least to do something useful?

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>→</kbd> move horizontally by half the screen width by default, but this can be changed using the `-#` (`--shift`) option. You can set this on the command-line or at runtime: in `less`, press <kbd>-</kbd><kbd>#</kbd> followed by the new shift amount. Shift amounts can be specified as absolute positions (*e.g.* 80), or a fraction of the screen width (*e.g.* 0.9).

<kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>)</kbd> is equivalent to <kbd>→</kbd>, <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>(</kbd> is equivalent to <kbd>←</kbd>. The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> variants don’t work for me, I have to use <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>{</kbd> and <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>}</kbd>.